# Deserialize json string array to string array

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net

Lets assume I have the following JSON Object:

```
{
    "Key": "\"QTuY+0m31w2QiZGl4h+W8w==\"",
    "Value":
    [
        "addgroup",
        "viewgroup",
        "editgroup"
    ]
}
```

How can I deserialize the `Value` part in a C# `string[]`?

The problem is, `string[]` is not the only type I have in the `Value` part, it can be everything, so I need to use dynamic.

I am using JSON.net and when I use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method I get a runtime binder exception.

This is the method I use to deserialize:

```
public async Task<Tuple<string, dynamic>> ReadCachingEntryAsync(string uri) {
    var data = tools.ReadEntry(Path.Combine(cacheFolder, uri.Replace("/", "")));
    var res = new Tuple<string, dynamic>(string.Empty, null);
    if (data != null) {
        var dat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
        res = new Tuple<string, dynamic>(dat.Key, dat.Value);
    }
    return res;
}
```

The `tools.ReadEntry(data)` returns a `byte[]` containing the data, from the binary formatted file.

Here is the class `KeyValuePair<K, V>`

```
[Serializable]
internal struct KeyValuePair<K, V> {
    public K Key { get; set; }
    public V Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the dynamic? You have a set model to serialize to JSON, so to do the reverse you deserialize JSON into a model

Comment: @No1_Melman I added some code, which shows why I need dynamic.

Comment: So, to clarify, you need a `dynamic` deserialization, but instead of having a `JArray`, you want it to make a `string[]` (or `int[]` or ...)? Would an `object[]` be sufficient?

Comment: @TimS. basically yes.

Comment: Please clean up your question so that it's clear and concise. It's way too much of a mess. Remove parts of your question that are no longer valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it's a `JArray` and implement special handling. E.g.

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"{""Key"": ""Something"", ""Value"": [""test"", ""test 2"", ""test 3""]}");
var dat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
var value = dat.Value;
if (value is JArray)
{
    var arrayType = value[0].Value.GetType().MakeArrayType();
    value = value.ToObject(arrayType);
}
var res = new Tuple<string, dynamic>(dat.Key, value);
```

Comment: I know, but JSON.net seems to convert it to this type: `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`

Comment: This is all true but if `GetString(data)` returns the json snippet at the top of the question then `DeserializeObject` will return null because there is no `KeyValuePair` of any types, just an anonymous json array.

Comment: @Knerd if you tell it it's a `dynamic`, sure. If you tell it it should be a `string[]`, then it converts it to `string[]`.

Comment: @TimS. to your edit, I can't use it, because the type of `Value` could be a `FlowDocument` (just saying a type)

Answer (score 3):

Just call `DeserializeObject<T>` replacing `T` with the type you intend to deserialize the input string into and json.NET will take care of the rest.

```
string[] json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(inputString);
```

EDIT:

Ok, so assuming all of your json is in the form of the example posted in EDIT 3 then waht you really want is;

```
public class KVPair
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string[] Value { get; set; }
}

KVPair pair = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KVPair>(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
```

Now this is fairly static but I'm not sure you actually need dynamic. If you do then you'll want the `Value` property to be of type `object` or `dynamic`. However, if you go that route then you will unfortunately have to deal with this unknown type. I'm really not knowledgeable on the `dynamic` type so I can't comment on how to deal with it later on but if say for example, the array could contain, ints, floats or strings and you made `Value` of type `object` you would have inspect the array later on, determine the underlying type and cast each of the items to that type before you could do anything useful with them. Hope that helps. If you're lucky you'll just be able to use the code I posted above as it's far simpler and is actually type safe.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I need to deserialize a dynamic, I gonna edit my question a bit.

Comment: @Knerd you make no sense... Firstly that does work. If you need the type to be `dynamic` then the other bit of code you posted works. Also, I believe you could have `dynamic` as the type you assign to while specifying `string[]` as the type parameter to `DeserlializeObject`. I don't use `dynamic` but if I remember correctly you can assign any type to it.

Comment: I use it to serialize any type. So in the braces could stand everything.

Comment: @Knerd I don't think you know what you're trying to do... Your question originally was just a json array with strings in it that you wanted to deserialize into a `string[]` then you posted some very advanced code that isn't even remotely similar to what you originally asked for... On top of that you've posted working code in all cases so I have no idea what you actually expect in an answer. This;`DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>` would not be able to deserialize the json you posted. It would return `null`, so again, I have no idea what you're expecting.

Comment: Oh right, I think I found an error. I gonna update again. I am sry for all that mess :(

Comment: @Knerd no worries. If you can more clearly communicate what you want I will try my best to answer it.

Comment: Sadly, it will be any type in there. Not just arrays, so the code wouldn't work. And that is exactly the reason why I need dynamic. The idea with typechecking after words is good, but won't work, because there are to many possible types.

Comment: Thank you @ecanmcdonnal TimS. has the solution for me.

Comment: @Knerd yeah he provided the code I was talking about in my answer.